# ansible serial do not continue when one host failed

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible [core 2.11.4] on RH 8.7

I realized that when I run ansible in serial mode ( to run some tasks on multiple hosts ) and task is failed on one host, then ansible breaks at all.
Is it a bug or ?
In non-serial mode it continue play on next hosts.

Comment: In non-serial mode, does it really continues the whole play or does it continues the actual task (which is indeed the expected behaviour)? Could you share a playbook to reproduce, its output and then the output you would want happening?

Comment: it continue play on other hosts

Answer (score 3):

What happens exactly is if all hosts fail in the serial batch then the entire play is stopped for all remaining hosts. If a single host in that batch still succeeds then it goes on to the next hosts. That behavior can be adapted by setting the [`max_fail_percentage` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#setting-a-maximum-failure-percentage) on the play to still fail if there are two many failed hosts.

The following is a dummy example just to show that by default all hosts are played if at least one succeeds in the serial batch. As you will see, I used 4 fake hosts and voluntarily failed even hosts.

- When using a batch size of 50% (which makes 2 hosts per batch) it goes through all hosts to the end (1 host fails over 2 in batch).
- If you lower the batch size to 25% (i.e. 1 host per batch) you will see it stops after the first encountered even failed host (i.e. all host in current batch failed).

Given the `fake_inventory.yml`:

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    "host[1:4]":
```

The `playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  serial: "{{ batch_size }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Doesn't fail
      command: ls

    - name: Fails for even hosts
      vars:
        is_even: "{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('host(\\d)', '\\1') | int % 2 == 0 }}"
      fail:
        msg: "I'm an even host, failing"
      when: is_even

    - name: Doesn't fail but played only on odd hosts since we failed even
      command: /bin/true
```

Gives (2 runs with different batch size)

```
$ ansible-playbook -i fake_inventory.yml -e batch_size=50% playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Doesn't fail] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2]
changed: [host1]

TASK [Fails for even hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host1]
fatal: [host2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "I'm an even host, failing"}

TASK [Doesn't fail but played only on odd hosts since we failed even] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Doesn't fail] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host3]
changed: [host4]

TASK [Fails for even hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host3]
fatal: [host4]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "I'm an even host, failing"}

TASK [Doesn't fail but played only on odd hosts since we failed even] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host3]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook -i fake_inventory.yml -e batch_size=25% playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Doesn't fail] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [Fails for even hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host1]

TASK [Doesn't fail but played only on odd hosts since we failed even] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Doesn't fail] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2]

TASK [Fails for even hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "I'm an even host, failing"}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: OK,I'll play with this... One question: If I want to run  task on all hosts independently in paralel...what is correct setup ?   max_fail_percentage: 0   ?

Comment: The best setup is don't use serial at all

Comment: Note: if your problem is that ansible does not spin up enough parallel ssh connection to your taste, you can adapt the `fork` parameter (which is from memory 5 by default). For a quick test => `ansible-plabook --forks 100 ....`. You can set that parameter either in environment of ansible.cfg

Comment: this fork parameter is used only in serial mode, right ?  
in default ( linear ) is still ansible  running hosts one by one, correct ?

Comment: no, serial and fork are totally different concepts. Forks = max number of parallel ssh connections. If your tasks needs to talk to 10 hosts and fork is 5, the sixth one will not start until one has finished. Serial = number of hosts addressed in a play batch. If you have 10 hosts and serial is 5, ansible will run the entire play on the first five host, then restart the play with the 5 next ones. And once again, for the issue you try to address, you do not want serial.

Comment: With or without serial, Ansible runs hosts in // as much as forks make it possible.

Comment: To be clear: if you want to run your patch play on 80 servers in // as fast as possible you need to remove serial from your play (i.e. have a single batch with 100% of servers) and set forks to 80 or more.

Comment: ok, you said that default fork is  5.. but when I run the playbook with default setup: no serial...why looks to me that ansible is going host by host, based on the output ?

Comment: What happens when you config more forks ? It's not because there is an order in the output that the commands where not running in //. So you probably used the correct word: il **looks** to you it's not in // but it actually is (for the number of configured forks). To see the current number of configured forks you can use `ansible-config dump | grep -i forks`.

Comment: ok, thanks for info, I'll play with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of the serial parameter.

According to the documentation :

> By default, Ansible runs in parallel against all the hosts in the pattern you set in the hosts: field of each play. If you want to manage only a few machines at a time, for example during a rolling update, you can define how many hosts Ansible should manage at a single time using the serial keyword

Adding the `serial: x` parameter on your playbook allow playing the task on `x` host in the same time.

For example, if you define `serial: 1`, the task is gonna be played on each host 1 by 1 : if one host failed, the play stop.

Comment: ok, so if want run e.g. patching tasks ( 80 hosts ) in more efficient way in serial mode...but I also want to see on which servers it is failed ( means not enable continue errors), then I have no options, right ? cause if 1 server failed than whole bunch is failed
e.g. I use serial 30%

Comment: You should handle your errors, or just write "ignore_errors: yes", it will continue with the next tasks even if 1 fails.